# How to pass parameter from an array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, datarow

I want to assign a value parameter dynamic through an array.
For example, the array `arr_param` will contain two value `[0] = "abc"`, `[1] = "ZYX"`
.Now, I will assign them .The problem here is that i must specify the correct elements `[0]`,`[1]` after run foreach, I tried do it but failed convert to int

```
string[] arr_param  =  array_parameter.Split(';');
foreach (DataRow parmRow in parmsDataTable.Rows)
{
    string parmName = parmRow[parmNameDataColumn].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parmName, arr_param[Convert.ToInt32(parmsDataTable.Rows)]);
}
```

I get error `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' to type 'System.IConvertible'`.

Comment: You get this exception because of this line :

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parmName, arr_param[Convert.ToInt32(parmsDataTable.Rows)]);

You're trying to convert a collection of DataRow which is parmsDataTable.Rows to an Int32 type. You can't do that convertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parmsDataTable.Rows` is a `DataRowCollection` and it can't be converted to `int`.

A **Simple** Solution:

```
string[] arr_param  =  array_parameter.Split(';');
int counter = 0;
foreach (DataRow parmRow in parmsDataTable.Rows)
{
   string parmName = parmRow[parmNameDataColumn].ToString();
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parmName, arr_param[counter++)]);
}
```

Or:

```
string[] arr_param  =  array_parameter.Split(';');
foreach (DataRow parmRow in parmsDataTable.Rows)
{
   string parmName = parmRow[parmNameDataColumn].ToString();
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parmName,arr_param[parmsDataTable.Rows.IndexOf(parmRow))]);
}
```

Comment: oh,two ways work and I think the first way easier to understand because it is clear.Thank you so much.